# How to split a string and add each item separately to a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to split a string which contains emails concatenated by comma. 
Example:

> email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com,

Method to split the string and add it to a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string[], string[]> GetMail(int id)
{
    var email = db.table1.ToList()
                .Where(r => r.idTable == id)
                .Select(em => em.email.Split(','));

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string[], string[]>();

    foreach (var mail in email)
        dictionary.Add(mail,mail);

    return dictionary;
}
```

But I need to be added each in a different index, because the result is:

```
[0] "email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com"
```

[image: result obtained by GetMail () method]

What I need is something like this:

```
[0] "email1@gmail.com"
[1] "email2@gmail.com"
[2] "email3@gmail.com"
```

Is it possible to do this? And how would I do it?

Comment: What's the point in using a dictionary if the keys and values are the same? You might as well use a `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: I can't see your screenshot, but maybe try `SelectMany` instead of `Select`.

Comment: I doubt an array of strings is a good key on a dictionary.

Comment: Looking at the return value, is it just an array you want, really?

Comment: You can use `SortedSet` if you need an order and don't want to have duplicates

Comment: Seems that `Select` should be before `Where`...

Comment: Use a *string array* as a key? Are you sure? How are you going to look up anything with an *array* key?

Comment: BTW LINQ has `ToDictionary`, `ToArray` and `ToList` methods. You could use `SelectMany(em => em.email.Split(','))` to get an enumerable of emails and pass it to a hashset, create an array etc

Comment: You use dictionaries when you need to look based on a certain value, for example you have pairs of usernames and emails, and you need the email address of certain user. Your method could just return the array result of split(',')

Comment: @Scott and @ Panagiotis Kanavos, just change Select() to SelectMany() and it works great, exactly what I needed. I did not know that method

Answer (score 3):

It seems, you want something like this (if you insist on `Dictionary`):

```
// Dictionary<int, string>:
//   Key   - int    - index
//   Value - string - eMail
public Dictionary<int, string> GetMail(int id) {
  var result = db.table1
    .AsEnumerable()                              // Do not materialize prematurely
    .Where(row => row.idTable == id)               
    .SelectMany(row => row.email.Split(','))     // flatten sequence
    .Select((email, index) => new {              // key and value specifictaion
       key = index,
       email = email })  
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.key,              // final dictionary 
                  pair => pair.email); 
}
```

---

But `Dictionary` is *redundant* in the context of the question: an array will provide the same fuctionality: `dict[key]` vs. `array[index]`

```
public string[] GetMail(int id) {
  var result = db.table1
    .AsEnumerable()                              // Do not materialize prematurely
    .Where(row => row.idTable == id)               
    .SelectMany(row => row.email.Split(','))     // flatten sequence
//  .Distinct() // if you want distinct eMails only  
    .ToArray(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the keys and values are going to be the same, there's no point in using a dictionary. It's simpler to use a `HashSet<string>`:

```
var emailString = // The comma-separated list of email addresses

var emails = new HashSet<string>(emailString.Split(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string emails = "email1@gmail.com,email2@gmial.com,email3@gmail.com";
        Dictionary<int, string> dictEmails = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        string[] arrEmails = emails.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < arrEmails.Length; i++)
        {
            dictEmails.Add(i, arrEmails[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for responding, I solved it using `SelectMany` instead of `Select` (honestly did not know that method).

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetMail(int id)
{
    var email = db.table1.ToList()
                .Where(r => r.idTable == id)
                 //SelectMany instead of Select
                .SelectMany(em => em.email.Split(','));

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var mail in email)
        dictionary.Add(mail,mail);

    return dictionary;
    //this returns:
    //[0]{[email1@gmail.com, email1@gmail.com]}
    //[1]{[email2@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com]}
    //[2]{[email3@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com]}
}
```

**What's the point in using a dictionary?**

It is a requirement of the application I'm developing, the idea is to use **key/value** to be consumed in a TokenBox, not matter if the key and value are the same (can be changed in the future) for example *username* and *email*

**I can't see your screenshot**

I apologize, I think it's because I don´t have enough points on stackoverflow to attach images :(

Comment: You should be careful with your dictionary. if a row contains the same address multiple times, you will get a `System.ArgumentException{"An item with the same key has already been added."}`. You could use `.Distinct()` as @[Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) suggested in his answer.